# How does a HashMap occupy memory?

Tags: java, memory, hashmap

I fear downvotes. Anyways, just like an ArrayList would have a contiguous memory allocation, a LinkedList would have a random memory allocation, how does HashMap occupy memory? Does it also take random chunks in the memory? Can I be briefed with a memory diagram of how map's buckets and the LinkedLists inside are located in the memory?

I hope this is not a bs question. Did not find much of information regarding Map's memory allocation diagram.

**EDIT**: The question I put has nothing to do with debugging/profiling. It's just about how a HashMap fits into the memory. I was unclear about it.

Comment: See http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/java-memory-model-simplified.html to find out more about how java memory is managed.

Comment: You can enhance your question, but putting a little context around why you need to know this information. Are you trying to debug slow performance, or memory usage?

Comment: @tinman - Nothing around debugging/profiling. Just wanted to get an idea of how a HashMap fits into the memory. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a combination of both.

There is an underlying, contiguous array that backs `HashMap`. The elements of this array are actually singly linked lists. Each time you add a key-value pair to the map, the key is hashed and a linked list entry is added to the corresponding slot of the backing array (i.e. the slot corresponding to the key's hash value).

For instance, a map that maps `k` to `v` might look like this:

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+-X-+-X-+-↓-+-X-+-X-+-X-+-X-+-X-+
          ↓
          ↓
        +---+
        | k |
        | - |
        | v |
        +---+
```

There is a long "table" that backs the map, and an entry that supports the specific `k`-to-`v` pairing.

It would probably be best for you to take a look at the [`HashMap` source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java) for yourself.

Comment: just one doubt. this allocation is actually 2D layout, not a linear 1D, right?

Comment: @NihalSharma Again, it's kind of a hybrid. It "grows" in a second dimension as you add more entries (if that's how you choose to think of it). Note that, from a performance standpoint, you actually want the map to be as flat as possible, so the backing array will be reallocated and increased in size if many entries are added.

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing almost every doubts I had regarding HashMap's memory layout.

Comment: And now you have a simple explanation. Here is the full on hardcore detail. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 0):

A hashmap is always an array where the hashcode can be determined to get the index of the array element(In jdk this is the entry) . Therefore, it should take a contiguous memory as well.